# arbeiten bei vs. arbeiten für

Tags: difference

Wir betrachten das folgende Beispiel:

Max ist Journalist.

> Er arbeitet beim StadtSpiegel / bei einer Zeitung.
>
> Er arbeitet für den StadtSpiegel / eine Zeitung.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen arbeiten *bei* und arbeiten *für*?

Ich selbst denke, arbeiten *bei* heißt, man ist bei der Institution oder Firma angestellt. Arbeiten *für* drückt aber aus, man arbeitet als Freiberufler für die Institution oder macht z.B. ein  Projekt für die Firma und bekommt für die geleistete Arbeit ein Honorar.

Comment: Hinweis: wenn es _bei**m** (=bei **dem**) Stadtspiegel_ heißt, muss es auch _für **den** Stadtspiegel_ heißen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Grundbedeutung von *bei* ist lokal, während *für* den Nutznießer bezeichnet. Das ist mit der geschilderten Konstellation kompatibel. Aber daraus folgt natürlich nicht, daß die Präpositionen in Verbindung mit *arbeiten* ausschließlich auf diese Weise gebraucht werden. Das wäre zunächst insofern unwahrscheinlich, als von außen nicht unbedingt zu erkennen ist, in welchem Arbeitsverhältnis eine Person steht, also ob z.B. ein Journalist eine Festanstellung hat oder ein Honorar bezieht; man wüßte also oft nicht, welche Präposition man gebrauchen soll.

Da auch bei Festanstellung der Arbeitgeber der Nutznießer ist, kann *für* stehen:

> Der Mann von Franziska Giffey ist seinen Beamtenjob los. Er arbeitete **für** das Land Berlin. [tagesspiegel](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/berlin/vorwurf-der-trickserei-giffeys-ehemann-wurde-aus-beamtenverhaeltnis-entlassen/25404588.html)

Der umgekehrte Fall gilt genauso: Zur lokalen Grundbedeutung von *bei* paßt es, kein Angestellter zu sein, wie im folgenden Fall.

> 196 Saisonkräfte, die **bei** Westfleisch arbeiten, wohnen derzeit in der Gemeinde Nottuln. [wn](https://www.wn.de/Muensterland/Kreis-Coesfeld/Nottuln/4199554-Corona-Ausbruch-Derzeit-zwei-Nottulner-Hotspots-im-Fokus)

(Die Tatsache, daß es sich nicht um Angestellte von Westfleisch handelt, ist hier von besonderer Bedeutung, da dadurch Kontrollen umgangen werden.)

Comment: Eine gewisse Tendenz ist aber unbestreitbar da, so dass man sagen könnte, mit *bei* drückt man häufiger ein Arbeitsverhältnis aus, während man bei Auftragsarbeiten häufig Formulierungen mit *für* benutzt. Aber es ist natürlich richtig, daraus nicht Ausschließlichkeit zu folgern. BTW: Wirklich gute Beispiele, die du zur Illustration herausgefischt hast!